# How can I improve performance score website in the gtmetrix?

Tags: seo, javascript, performance, pagerank, page-speed

I test my web with gtmetrix. The result like this :

[image]

I want to improve grade of add expires headers, compress component with gzip and all recommendation which has a bad grade

How can I do it?

**Update** :

See my update image :

[image]

[image]

Tell me how to improve only 4 recommendations. That is add expires headers, make fewer http requests, use cookie free domain and reduce dns lookups

Comment: It literally gives you a list of seven suggestions.    That is far too many to describe each in detail here.

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller I update my question

Comment: Each of those could be its own question.  Some of them are already answered here.  We have 143 questions about expires headers already: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=expires%20headers

Comment: @Stephen Ostermille Well. Can it be briefly explained or given a reference for each recommendation? So I can find out what I'm supposed to do. Your answer can be useful for the future